# Tensorflow training models in sequence leads to different results

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have let's say MODEL2 (with a specific, not changing set of parameters). I can repeat training that model and I get the same results everytime as expected.

Then I implemented some tests which train models in sequence.

When running MODEL1 and after that MODEL2. MODEL2 has different results than running it standalone (first case above). Why?

I tried to initialize tensorflow from scratch everytime I train a new model but it doesn't seem to help. Also `tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()` doesn't help.

Someone has an idea?

Comment: i don't understand. are you trying to do transfer learning from model1 to model2, or just running stand-alone models in sequence.

Comment: Just stand-alone models in sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating models in a separate graph. The following pattern is useful if you are running multiple tf models and sessions in the same process.

```
mygraph = tf.Graph()
with mygraph.as_default():
    # create or saver.restore tf variables here

session = tf.Session(graph=mygraph)

with session.as_default():
    with mygraph.as_default():
        session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        # train tf here
```